# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Collapse Menu Right and Width always XS

Tags: asp.net

I need to accomplish the following preferably with HTML and not CSS:

1. Menu always collapsed on any screen size
2. On XS or small screen the toggle menu options are full screen
3. On MD or medium and larger screens the toggled menu options should be at the right and a fixed width like 2 columns more like a pulldown menu.

The first 2 requirements are default behavior, but I can't figure out number 3 and my code is below:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top">

    <div class="d-flex w-100 flex-nowrap">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="~/images/matrixforce-white-logo.svg" width="343" height="54" class="img-fluid" alt="Matrixforce White Logo" />
        </a>

        <span class="ml-auto my-md-auto"><a href="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/Matrixforce@matrixforce.com/bookings/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-3 d-none d-lg-block" role="button">Schedule Consult <span class="fas fa-play"></span></a></span>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item py-md-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-md-4" href="@Url.Action("Index","Guardian")">Guardian</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-md-4" href="@Url.Action("Index","Orbit")">Orbit</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-md-4" href="@Url.Action("Index","Phoenix")">Phoenix</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-md-4" href="@Url.Action("Index","Overwatch")">Overwatch</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-md-4" href="@Url.Action("Index","Support")">Support</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-md-4" href="@Url.Action("Contact","Home")">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 d-flex flex-nowrap ml-3 mr-auto" method="get" action="@Url.Action("Search","Home")">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>

        <div class="d-lg-none d-xl-none">
            <a href="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/Matrixforce@matrixforce.com/bookings/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" type="button" class="btn btn-success ml-3 my-3" role="button">Schedule Consult <span class="fas fa-play"></span></a>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with an always expanded Navbar but with a pulldown using the toggler-icon to achieve this result.

```
<div class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="/images/matrixforce-white-logo.svg" width="343" height="54" class="img-fluid" alt="Matrixforce White Logo" />
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-success d-none d-lg-block ms-md-auto me-md-4" href="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/Matrixforce@matrixforce.com/bookings/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" type="button" role="button">Schedule Consult<span class="fas fa-play ms-1"></span></a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end mt-3" style="min-width:276px;" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item my-2 py-2" href="/guardian/">Guardian</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item my-2 py-2" href="/orbit/">Orbit</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item my-2 py-2" href="/phoenix/">Phoenix</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item my-2 py-2" href="/overwatch/">Overwatch</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item my-2 py-2" href="/support/">Support</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item my-2 py-2" href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 d-flex flex-nowrap mx-2 py-2 " method="get" action="/search/">
                        <input class="form-control me-sm-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </li>
                <li class="d-lg-none d-xl-none">
                    <a class="btn btn-success ms-2 my-2" href="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/Matrixforce@matrixforce.com/bookings/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" type="button" role="button">Schedule Consult<span class="fas fa-play ms-1"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```